# Twitter follower request approval & blocking automation

Tags: .net, automation, twitter

Need to automate the approval of follower requests and block contacts. We will have a list of approved users in our database, so if anyone requests and is on that list I need to approve them. If they are followers and they fall off the list then we need to block them.

I see there is an API call to block them [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/blocks/create). So I am thinking I can use that by issuing multiple http requests.

I still need to automate the approval of followers. Has anyone been able to do this? Even with a script that will scan the page? I know there isn't an API call for approving but is there any other decent way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension for Chrome in order to accept/approve all follower requests
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-accept-all-button/aoldpodihmiiijjcgkcddgcdhaloejdf